# Camel: How to build a route conditionally from configuration?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a `RouteBuilder` subclass which sets up my Camel routes. It is constructed by Spring. Initially it looked something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(...)
    .process(...)
    .to(...)
}
```

What I would like to do is add an additional endpoint routing based on configuration. There is a Properties file that Spring uses to create the `RouteBuilder` bean and one of the fields it sets is `boolean addAnotherEndpoint`. If this boolean is true I want to add another `to`. If it's false I want it to fall back to its current behaviour. So I changed it to this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(...)
    .process(...)
    .to(...)
    .choice()
        when(constant(addAnotherEndpoint)).to(...)
    .endChoice();
}
```

While this appears to have the desired behaviour I'm having issues writing unit tests for it (because it's pulling the value of `addAnotherEndpoint` from the properties file even though I'm trying to override it in my tests). Is there a better way of handling this? Will my current method have any unintended side-effects?

**EDIT:**

I am testing using a `CamelSpringTestSupport` subclass (using JUnit tests). In the `@Before` method I create an `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` that replaces all endpoints with mocks. In my `@Test`, I am attempting to override the value of `addAnotherEndpoint` which is taken from the Properties file:

```
@Test
public void testConditionalRouting() throws Exception {
    context.start();
    MyRouteBuilder routeBuilder = (MyRouteBuilder) applicationContext.getBean("myRouteBuilder");
    routeBuilder.setAddAnotherEndpoint(true);
    getMockEndpoint("myMockEndpoint").expectedMessageCount(1);
    sendMockMessage();
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    context.stop();
}
```

There is a corresponding test that sets `addAnotherEndpoint` to `false` and asserts that 0 messages were received. The problem is that overriding the value of this variable doesn't seem to be working. One test passes and the other fails depending on whether my Properties file says the value should be `true` or `false`. What this suggests to me is that the route is being constructed before I override setting (and therefore also before the context is started). I checked in a debugger and the setting *is* correctly overridden. It just doesn't seem to have any affect.

**EDIT 2:**

From my `AdviceWithRouteBuilder`:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    replaceFromWith(MOCK_FROM_ENDPOINT);
    interceptSendToEndpoint(FIRST_TO_ENDPOINT)
            .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to(MOCK_FIRST_TO_ENDPOINT);
    weaveById(MY_PROCESSOR_ENDPOINT).replace()
            .to(MOCK_MY_PROCESSOR_ENDPOINT);
    weaveById(SECOND_TO_ENDPOINT).replace()
            .to(MOCK_SECOND_TO_ENDPOINT);
}
```

This replaces each EIP with a mock endpoint. I have 4 tests that rely on these and they seem to be working as expected, the only problem is the conditional routing.

Aside from JUnit annotations, the only annotations on my test class are `@Override` on `isUseAdviceWith()` (returns true) and `createApplicationContext()`, which returns a new Spring Application Context.

I ran my tests without `context.start()` and the only one that passed was the one that asserts 0 messages were received (which makes sense if the route was not started). So I don't believe the context is being auto-started.

Comment: This looks like a very normal route to me. I guess the only issue would be the way you are testing it. On a live environment, this route should be okay. Can you share how you are testing it? Then we can fix that too. BTW, it would be simpler if you use a Filter, instead of Choice that only has one condition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using a `CamelSpringTestSupport` subclass to test it. I'll update the question to include this.

Comment: May I also see your AdviceWithRouteBuilder block? Also, does your test class have any annotations? Can you also remove context.start(); from the beginning of your tests, and run them to see if the context is auto starting anyway? If so, the problem is there...

Comment: Updated the question again.

Comment: You have done a very good analysis there. If not me, I'm sure somebody else will be able to help you with this. Just before your Choice, what do you see if you log addAnotherEndpoint? As this is the only thing that stays unsolved for me, could you please share how you override this property?

Comment: `addAnotherEndpoint` is set to whatever is in the properties file. Inspecting my RouteBuilder in a debugger, I noticed that the route definitions are actually created when the application context is created, not when the camel context is started. This means that I need to change my application context definition. I'm not sure how that's even possible on a per-test-case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working:

My test was fine but I had to rethink how I was building my route. What was happening was at the time the Spring context was created, the route was being built. It checked the value of `addAnotherEndpoint` at that time and set the `constant` based on that. But `boolean` is a primitive value, which means it was passed by value. Why does this matter? Because the `constant()` function simply sets the route based on the value of that constant *at the time the route is built*. Changing it later on via Spring had no affect because the value had already been read. What I needed to do was make it pass an object as a predicate so I could manipulate that same object later on as a bean.

Also, I changed from a `choice()` to a `filter()` as suggested. Here's the finished product:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(...)
    .process(...)
    .to(...)
    .choice()
        when(myBooleanPredicate).to(...)
    .endChoice();
}
```

And my custom predicate that could be manipulated via Spring:

```
public class BooleanPredicate implements Predicate {
  private boolean value;

  @Override
  public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(boolean value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
```

This `BooleanPredicate`'s internal `value` is set to `addAnotherPredicate`. It is reread each time the route is run since the `BooleanPredicate` is passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found that

```
.when(exchange-> foo()==true)
```

is sufficient.